# Invalid Job Recommendations Tag Link On Profile Activity Tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On my User Profile Activity Tab I had Job Recommendations that involved the c# and f# tags (with the hover text "show jobs tagged 'c#'").  However, the tag links for both of those tags were incorrect.

The link for the c# tag was:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%2523`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%2523) 
instead of the expected 
[`https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%23`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%23)

Notice the incorrect `%25` in the link which causes a 404.

[image]

Based on network traffic seems like the incorrect tag link is generated on the server and returned via XHR. The behavior is the same on the latest version of Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Comment: **Hot tip** for reviewers: [[meta-tag:bug]] reports that have been explicitly tagged [[meta-tag:status-completed]] don't really need to be closed as non-reproducible. That's silly, a waste of your close votes and other reviewers' time, and ultimately counter-productive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your report. This has now been fixed. We were double-encoding jobs recommendations URLs, which caused `c#` and `f#` tags to be incorrectly rendered as `c%2523` and `f%2523`. Should be all good and up in production now.